# iOS Cocos2d CCLabelTTF Set String Ends in Exc Bad Access

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

This has cost me many hours during the development of an iPhone game. Any help is greatly appreciated!

## Setup

- ARC
- Cocos2d 2.0

## Problem

- EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I set the string on a CCLabelTTF
- Happens roughly 1 out of every 5 tries

## Code

The following code is from the class LevelSelectionLayer. This class is the delegate to another class that handles a grid of levels and touch interaction.

#### In LevelSelectionLayer.h

```
@property (strong) NSArray *difficulties;
@property (strong) CCLabelTTF *difficultyLabel;
@property (strong) SlidingMenuGrid *slidingMenuGrid;
```

#### In LevelSelectionLayer.m

```
-(id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.difficulties = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Easy", @"Intermediate", @"Hard", nil];

        [self initDifficultyLabel];
        [self initGrid];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initDifficultyLabel
{
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    self.difficultyLabel = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:[self.difficulties objectAtIndex:0] fontName:FONT_BOLD fontSize:18.0f];
    self.difficultyLabel.position = ccp(size.width / 2 + 3, size.height / 2 + 63);
    self.difficultyLabel.color = CCC3_DARK_COLOR;
    [self addChild:self.difficultyLabel z:5];
}
```

#### In LevelSelectionLayer.m (continued). This is a delegate method that is called from the grid class mentioned above.

```
-(void) slidingGridDidChangePage
{
    // Get curent page
    int currentPage = self.slidingMenuGrid.iCurrentPage;
    CCLOG(@"currentPage:%d", currentPage); // Always prints correct number

    // Adjust pagination display
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        CCSprite *bub = [self.pageBubbles objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == currentPage) {
            bub.displayFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"pageSelected.png"];
        }
        else {
            bub.displayFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"page.png"];            
        }
    }

    // Adjust difficulty labeL
    /******* BREAKS HERE *******/
    self.difficultyLabel.string = (NSString *)[self.difficulties objectAtIndex:currentPage];
    //self.difficultyLabel.string = @"Test"; // Breaks every once in a while as well
}
```

Comment: enable zombie objects (in Xcode edit target's build scheme) to see if the crash is due to a released object

Comment: I enabled zombies for both the simulator and the device. However, in the simulator there is no crash at all. 
For the device there is nothing helpful in the output window. Other than that it just says Thread 8 - sgxBindResource and EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8)

Answer (score 0):

most probably, difficultyLabel is released somewhere during the app's flow. Since you're adding it to your Layer right after it's created(it's retained from it until you remove it or release your layer ), you don't need to alloc it, and release it anywhere.

Comment: I'm using ARC so I can't really release it. And don't you have to use alloc?
Also, I did a break just before setting the string and the label exists and is not 0x0000.  It actually has properties.  Any ideas?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually means a memory issue, usually a zombie. Have  you tried Instruments to watch for zombies and retain counts, as LearnCocos2d already suggested ? When these errors happen occasionally but not always, it's probably another part of your code that creates the problem.

Comment: I have tried, but the error doesn't even occur on the simulator. It only happens on the device..

Comment: Have you tried instruments running on your device ? you should try that anyway as it's more accurate and faster

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into what I think is the same issue. It's only happening on release builds for device. When I enable zombie detection, I am alerted at the time of the crash that the "setPosition" method is being invoked on a deallocated object (my CCLabelTTF), which occurs in the next line after I create my label. For some reason it appears that the label is being released by ARC between the time it is created, but before I can send any messages to it. Other info that may be helpful: I'm assigning the label to an ivar declared with the __unsafe_unretained directive, as I want to just maintain a "weak" reference to the label so that I can modify it later without having to fetch it from it's parent via a tag (the label is added as a child of the layer it is created in, which should retain it). This does not happen when I use a temporary variable for setting up my label. Also strange to me is that all other CCNode subclasses behave the exact same way in terms of being allocated, but I am only having this issue with CCLabelTTF.

EDIT: also worth mentioning is that I am using one of CCLabelTTF's convenience methods (which returns an autoreleased object) to create the label, so in theory that object should persist well outside of the scope of the function it is created in, until the auto release pool is drained.

EDIT: I've solved my problem. Not sure if it will help the OP, but here it is: use __weak instead of __unsafe_unretained. AFAIK this will only work for apps that support iOS 5.0+, but for me that's fine, I don't ever plan on supporting anything less at this point.

Comment: So, assigning the label to a temporary variable, and *then* assigning to my ivar seems to work around the problem. This definitely seems to be a bug with ARC, though I'm still confused why it only occurs with CCLabelTTFs

Comment: I'll try the temporary variable! Thanks for your help on this. Strange that ARC is acting this way.